# Error when to trying to add custom Helm repo to local from GitLab

Tags: gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I created a helm repo using command: **helm create my-repo** and made some minor changes to the files in the templates folder, packaged this using **helm package my-repo** which in turn generated my-repo-0.0.1.tgz and then **helm repo index .** to generate index.yaml file.

I have created a repository in GitLab and pushed my-repo-0.0.1.tgz and index.yaml files to the GitLab repository, the issue I'm facing here is when I run the command
**helm repo add my-repo https://gitlab.com/myorg/mycompany/my-helm-repo/-/blob/master** I am seeing below error

**Error: looks like "https://gitlab.com/myorg/mycompany/my-helm-repo/-/blob/master" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch  https://gitlab.com/myorg/mycompany/my-helm-repo/-/blob/master/index.yaml: 503 Service Unavailable.**

Any idea what is wrong here and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw.githubusercontent.com` to add your repo.

```
helm repo add --username <username> --password '<github token>' <repo-name> 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/organization-name/helm-repo-name/branch-master/'
```

The `raw.githubusercontent.com` domain is used to serve unprocessed versions of files stored in GitHub repositories. So it will returns the raw content of files stored in Github.

Comment: we don't use GitHub. So my only option is to use GitLab

Comment: @NeverStopLearning did you solved pulling the chart? Can you share some insides how you have solved this?